# ¿Cómo se evalúa el operador ternario en PHP?

Tags: php, operador-ternario

Cuando se evalúa el operador ternario, la siguiente expresión:

```
$var = true ? '1' : false ? '2' : '3';
```

da como resultado **`'2'`**

Según mi lógica si la primera expresión que es verdadera debería mostrar el siguiente valor osea para mi el resultado debería ser `1` y no evaluarse la siguiente expresión y en caso de evaluarse su valor seria `'3'`.

¿Cómo actúa la precedencia de operadores para evaluar de esta forma?

Comment: ¿Y si pruebas a usar paréntesis? `$var = ((true) ? '1' : ((false) ? '2' : '3'));`

Comment: La pregunta me parece muy clara, no entiendo los votos negativos

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Según la tabla de precedencia de operadores:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

El operador ternario tiene asociación a la izquierda por lo que tu expresión:

```
$var = true ? '1' : false ? '2' : '3';
```

se interpreta como:

```
$var = (true ? '1' : false) ? '2' : '3';
```

Luego, primero se resuelve el paréntesis quedando:

```
$var = '1' ? '2' : '3';
```

Y esto último dando como resultado '2'

Comment: @AníbalJorqueraCornejo si la respuesta te sirvio, recuerda marcarla como aceptada. Las gracias en los comentarios no son necesarias. ;)